# Save CheckBox selections for contacts

Tags: android, android-listview

In my app, I have a list of contacts retrieved from the address book. I want to be able to press a button to save the selected contacts to the server. It works if ALL of the contacts are selected; however, if I choose just a couple random contacts then press the button to save them, the app crashes and says I didn't select any. So what I did was put mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() after the save button is pressed before the contacts sync, but that didn't change anything. Any ideas?

**Answer**
I moved the method to save the contacts to the server from outside of the adapter to inside the adapter, then used

```
 if(holder.checkBox.isChecked()) { //sync }
```

and that syncs each item that has a checked box

Comment: Paste your code here.